# How to group by month, quarter or year using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given the following case:

```
a <- c(rep("A", 25), rep("B", 25))
b <- rep(as.Date(c("2007-01-01")) + seq(60,1500,60),2)
c <- runif(50, 0, 1000)
d <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

If I visualize this using ggplot2 I get a nice bar chart

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x=b, y=c, fill=a)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
scale_x_date(breaks = as.Date(c("2007-01-01", "2008-01-01", "2009-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2011-01-01")), 
minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image: 1]

Note: One bar represents one observation.

However, I would like to be able to quickly group these observations together and have only 1 bar chart per year or 1 bar chart for every 2 years.

How is it possible to do this using ggplot2?

Comment: You could aggregate using `stat_summary` in the veins of `library(lubridate); d <- transform(d, mon=month(b), qrt=quarter(b), yr=year(b)); p <- ggplot(d, aes(y=c, fill=a)) + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="bar"); p + aes(x=yr) + xlab("year"); p + aes(x=paste(yr, qrt, sep="-")) + xlab("qrt"); p + aes(x=yr %/% 2) + xlab("2 yrs")`.

Comment: did you try `geom_bar( fill= quarter) `. In case if u have a column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot2` does not do aggregation by itself. You can use the base **R** `aggregate` function for it or packages like `dplyr`, `plyr` or `data.table`.

A `data.table` solution would be:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)
setDT(d)[,b := as.IDate(b)]
ggplot(d[,sum(c), by=.(a, year(b))], aes(x=year, y=V1, fill=a)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Obviously you can take whatever statistic you like instead of `sum` and also group by something else then year in the `d[,sum(c), by=.(a, year(b))]` call.

The Result would be:

[image]